Driver works with undetected_chromedriver but not with seleniumbase
I am currently creating an application which involves 2 webdrivers. One webdriver uses the undetected_chromedriver library and one uses seleniumbase in UC mode:
driver1 = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, user_multi_procs=True, headless=True)
driver2 = seleniumbase.Driver(uc=True, headless2=True, uc_subprocess=True, incognito=True)

driver1 works fine, however, when attempting to run driver2, sometimes I receive the following  error:
session not created: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:63728
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7DA6E2775+28773]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA64AFB0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA4E5359]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA4D6ECD]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA5260A2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA51B025]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA56A2DC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA5698C0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA55ED43]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA52A548]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA52B6B1]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7DAA0F45D+3358029]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7DAA2430D+3443709]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7DAA183FD+3394797]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7DA7A929B+842635]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA65654F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA651FA4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA65213D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DA641629]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF9BD27374+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF9CF9CC91+33]


I have looked for solutions but have had no success, does anybody know why I am receiving this error?

For Linux, you'll want Xvfb instead of Headless Mode.
Use the SB() context manager format:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, test=True, xvfb=True, incognito=True) as sb:
    sb.activate_cdp_mode(URL)

If using CDP Mode (which is stealthier than regular UC Mode), you'll want to use the sb.cdp methods. Examples in SeleniumBase/examples/cdp_mode.
Otherwise (if using regular UC Mode), then don't activate CDP Mode.
You can access the raw driver methods from regular UC Mode with sb.driver.

Thanks, what should I do if I am using Windows?

On Windows, there's a GUI. Use a regular, visible browser.
